# Simulate real click programmatically

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using this code to identify if click is programmatically triggered.

How should I edit `$('#x').trigger('click')` to simulate real click? (hasOwnProperty should return true 'Real')

```
$('#x').click(function(e) {
    if(e.hasOwnProperty('originalEvent')) {
        $('#out').append('<li>Real</li>');
    } else {
        $('#out').append('<li>Unreal</li>');
    }
});
$('#y').click(function() {
    $('#x').trigger('click'); //how to edit this
});
```

Comment: *Simulate a real click* is an oxymoron. If you simulate a click, it is not real, by definition.

Comment: ultimately what keeps you from accepting any of the answers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So essentially what you want is **not possible**. A real click - with all the elevated permissions (like `window.open` no being blocked by popup blockers) cannot be simulated.

If you do insist though...  Your particular case might be solved by dispatching a click event programmatically to the element. But it is in many ways can be error prone.

```
var event = new Event('click');

$('#x')[0].dispatchEvent(event);
```

Comment: Or just `$('#x')[0].click();`

Comment: you cant be sure of the implementation of that... and I had issues with only jQuery receivers firing...

Comment: Ya but i'd be more sure than passing invalid formated object to `dispatchEvent()` method where you should pass DOM event, not jq one. So indeed, none of these methods are safe

Answer (score 0):

You could have just as easily add an extra parameter to your click function instead of adding a property to the event object:

```
$('#x').click(function(e, orig) {
    if(orig) {
        $('#out').append('<li>Real</li>');
    } else {
        $('#out').append('<li>Unreal</li>');
    }
});
$('#y').click(function() {
    $('#x').trigger('click', true);
});
```

Otherwise, if you insist on adding a property to the event object you'll need to do:

```
$('#x').trigger($.Event( "click", { originalEvent: true } ));
```